# How to hide or dock result grid panel/toolbar in MySQL Workbench 6.3?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am seeing the following panel in the result grid.

[image]

Based on the research I've done, for many people this panel is docked. However, in my application it's hidden then displayed upon hovering in that area. This has become very annoying because it's hard to use the scrollbar there.

I've looked all over in the preferences and toolbars but can't find a way to disable it.

Does anyone know how I can get rid of it altogether or make it static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably activated the "hidden" mode. Klick on the small icon right beside the bar:

[image]

Comment: I thought I had already tried this. But apparently I was not clicking on it correctly because it was moving around so much. Thanks.